# Sweet alert not working with $_session

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, session, sweetalert

I want to show a sweet alert if the sql is true, but it's not working. 
Here is the back-end part.

```
<?php
include "../../../config/config.php";

if (isset($_POST['submit-slider']))
 {
    $title = $_POST['title-slider'];
    $description = $_POST['description-slider'];
    $street = $_POST['street-slider'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone-slider'];
    $trip = $_POST['trip-slider'];
    $web = $_POST['web-slider'];
    $email = $_POST['email-slider'];

    $target_dir = "../../../img/homepage/screen_4/";
    $target_file2 = "" . basename($_FILES["img-slider"]["name"]);
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["img-slider"]["name"]);


    $uploadOk = 1;

    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);


    // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        //  header("Location: /dashboard/views/slider/add_slider.php");
        // if everything is ok, try to upload file
    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["img-slider"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {


            //echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["img"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
        } else {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }


        $query = "INSERT INTO images(title,
                                  description,
                                  street_1,
                                  phone,
                                  url,
                                  trip_link,
                                  img,
                                  email
                                )

                                    VALUES ('" . $title . "', '"
                . $description . "', '"
                . $street . "', '"
                . $phone . "', '"
                . $web . "', '"
                . $trip . "', '"
                . $target_file2 . "', '"
                . $email . "')";

        $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

        if ($result) {

            $_SESSION['succes_slider'] = 1;
            header("Location: /dashboard/views/slider/add_slider.php");
        } else {
//            $_SESSION['succes_slider'] = 0;
            header("Location: /dashboard/views/slider/add_slider.php");
        }
    }
}
?>
```

And here is the page where i want to show the sweet-alert.

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
    header("Location: /dashboard/login.php");
}


//include "../config/config.php";
include "../../components/header.php";
include "../../components/menu.php";


if (isset($_SESSION['succes_slider']) == 1) {
    echo"  <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                swal('Succes','','succes');
            });
            </script>";
}


?>

</aside>


<!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
    <section class="content-header">
        <h1>
            Hello
            <small>HI</small>
        </h1>
    </section>

    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">
```

I don't know why is not working and I know ..my code is vulnerable at MySql Injection but I'm not working at this right now.

The sweet alert is working on my login page, if can help someone to know why is not working on other page..

Here is the back-end of the login

```
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);



    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='" . $email . "' AND password='" . md5($password) . "'";


    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);


    $row_count = mysqli_num_rows($result);


    if ($row_count != 0) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);


        $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
        $_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];




        header("Location: /dashboard/index.php");
    } else {
        $_SESSION['error'] = 1;
        header("Location: /dashboard/login.php");
    }
}
```

The front-end for the login is the same with other page, the difference is the name of the session.

Comment: You have to include `session_start()` in all files where you use `$_SESSION` variables.
Also, you might want to escape your inputs with prepared statements or `mysqli_real_escape_string` to prevent SQL-injection.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the session_start before using any of the $_SESSION. Moreover, I saw you are using include, I suggest you move to require because it will trigger errors in case you don't have a file.
Another suggestion would be to check if the files exists before including/requiring them in your script.

```
<?php
// include "../../../config/config.php";
// if a file is missing include won't trigger an error
require "../../../config/config.php";

// always include session_start where you plan to use $_SESSION
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['submit-slider']))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer..but still not working :(. And thanks for your advice!:)

Comment: I saw you mentioned a .js error, you must give us more details so that we can analyze your problem better...

Comment: Problem was solved. The solution was to start the session and the second problem was from sweet alert I wrote wrong the name of the message type. Thank you! P.S: I'm romanian too :D.

Answer (score 0):

In your first file, you have to use `session_start()` too.

You're assigning `$_SESSION['succes_slider'] = 1;`, but there's no session started in this file. 
So just use `session_start();` on the first line of your first code and it works.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it's not working yet:( ..and i found an error in console  "Uncaught ReferenceError: logStr is not defined sweetalert.min.js:1"

Answer (score 0):

I think that you did not used the Session Started code tag on the file...

Add this just after your require:

```
session_start();
```